# Azure web site Publishing profile and Visual Studio Code Editor?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

Possible to deploy to azure web site using Visual Studio Code editor and an Azure Publishing profile?

How and Where?

Comment: Any update?If you feel my answer is useful /helpful. Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I suggest you could use git to publish your project to the azure.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Create a web app service in the azure and set the Deployment credentials as below:

Notice: Remember the user name and password.

[image]

Set the password and user name:[image]

2.Set the azure web application deployment options to local git.

[image]

Choose the source:

[image]

3.Copy the git url in web service overview:

[image]
4.Open your VS code and right click the project, select the open in the command prompt

[image]

5.In the opened windows add below command:

Notice: Change the url as your copied url

```
git remote add azure https://account@yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/estruyf-publish.git 
git config credential.helper store 
git push -u azure master
```

Then it will fired a login window to type the username and password.

[image]

The result as below:

[image]

Notice: My VS code version is 1.21.1. It will automatic install the Git. If your VS code doesn't contain the git, you need install it firstly. You could refer to this [article](https://www.eliostruyf.com/publishing-web-projects-from-visual-studio-code-to-azure-with-git/).